# How to import ldif file using unboundid-ldap-sdp?

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, ldif

I exported the following ldif file from an LDAP server and am now trying to import it so that I can replicate the directory I exported it from:

```
dn: cn=MYCOMPANY Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: MYCOMPANY Users
gidNumber: 1001

dn: cn=jim smith,cn=MYCOMPANY Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
givenName: jim
cn: jim smith
sn: smith
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/users/arolls
uid: jsmith
uidNumber: 1038
userPassword: {MD5}X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==

dn: cn=dave jones,cn=MYCOMPANY Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
givenName: dave
userPassword: {MD5}FhCDh0PMkOPk/dp0goLZuA==
loginShell: /bin/sh
cn: dave jones
sn: dave
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/users/dave
uid: dave
uidNumber: 1006
```

I'm trying to import it using

```
LDIFReader r = new LDIFReader(resourceAsStream);
LDIFChangeRecord readEntry = null;
while ((readEntry = r.readChangeRecord()) != null) {
  readEntry.processChange(server);
}
```

I'm getting the following error, would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
LDAPException(resultCode=65 (object class violation), errorMessage='Unable to add entry 'cn=MYCOMPANY Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com' because it violates the provided schema: The entry contains object class posixGroup which is not defined in the schema. The entry contains attribute cn which is not allowed by its object classes and/or DIT content rule. The entry contains attribute gidNumber which is not defined in the schema. The entry's RDN contains attribute cn which is not allowed to be included in the entry.', diagnosticMessage='Unable to add entry 'cn=MYCOMPANY Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com' because it violates the provided schema: The entry contains object class posixGroup which is not defined in the schema. The entry contains attribute cn which is not allowed by its object classes and/or DIT content rule. The entry contains attribute gidNumber which is not defined in the schema. The entry's RDN contains attribute cn which is not allowed to be included in the entry.')

at com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer.add(InMemoryDirectoryServer.java:1382)
at com.unboundid.ldif.LDIFAddChangeRecord.processChange(LDIFAddChangeRecord.java:213)
at com.github.trevershick.test.ldap.LdapServerResource.loadLdifFiles(LdapServerResource.java:156)
at com.github.trevershick.test.ldap.LdapServerResource.start(LdapServerResource.java:81)
at org.rory.util.services.ldap.TestLDAPAuthUIUtilUsingInMemoryLdapServer.startup(TestLDAPAuthUIUtilUsingInMemoryLdapServer.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.rory.util.services.ldap.TestLDAPAuthUIUtilUsingInMemoryLdapServer.shutdown(TestLDAPAuthUIUtilUsingInMemoryLdapServer.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got this working thanks to Neil via https://sourceforge.net/p/ldap-sdk/discussion/1001257/thread/08ceb8da/?limit=25#65b0.

Specifically, I needed to do two things:

1. Disable schema checking via:

InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig.setSchema(null)

1. Added the following 4 lines to the top of the ldif:

dn: dc=mycompany,dc=com

objectClass: top

objectClass: domain

dc: mycompany

Answer (score 0):

The objectClass `posixGroup` was not found in your directory server schema. `posixGroup` is defined by [RFC 2307-bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-02). You'll need to add that objectClass and its associated attributes to the schema and then add your LDIF change records.

Comment: Thanks, so do you know how to add it to the schema using the unboundid-ldap-sdk?

Comment: It depends on the server that is in use. If the server supports an LDAP backend for schema, then the schema can be added using a `ModifyRequest`.