# How to import ldif file in a manner insensitive to entries order

Tags: import, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, ldif, apache-directory

Based on [this](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/in-memory-directory-server.html) I use following code to start in memory ldap server

```
// Create the configuration to use for the server.
InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig config =
     new InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig("dc=example,dc=com");
config.addAdditionalBindCredentials("cn=Directory Manager", "password");
config.setSchema(null); //!!! without this line I get an error thanks for https://stackoverflow.com/a/17921875/2674303
// Create the directory server instance, populate it with data from the
// "test-data.ldif" file, and start listening for client connections.
InMemoryDirectoryServer ds = new InMemoryDirectoryServer(config);
ds.importFromLDIF(true, "test-data.ldif");
ds.startListening();

// Get a client connection to the server and use it to perform various
// operations.
LDAPConnection conn = ds.getConnection();
SearchResultEntry entry = conn.getEntry("dc=example,dc=com");

// Do more stuff here....

// Disconnect from the server and cause the server to shut down.
conn.close();
ds.shutDown(true);
```

I want to import structure from exsiting ldap server.
I use apach directory studio for that:
[image]

I save the content to the file with name `test-data.ldif`

And when I run the code above I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" LDAPException(resultCode=32 (no such object), errorMessage='Unable to add entry 'CN=8437C3D8-7689-4200-BF38-79E4AC33DFA0,CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=example,DC=com' because its parent entry 'CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=example,DC=com' does not exist in the server.', matchedDN='DC=example,DC=com', ldapSDKVersion=6.0.9, revision=42839ddf0d77d954805fbbe3cce73a792af40474)

I've found out that the root cause that
entry with dn

```
CN=8437C3D8-7689-4200-BF38-79E4AC33DFA0,CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=example,DC=com
```

is the first entry in the exported file and if to rearrange entries manually to make sure that all parents are created above - export will be successful. So for that entry we should place defiition of entry

```
DC=example,DC=com
```

then

```
CN=System,DC=example,DC=com
```

then

```
CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=example,DC=com
```

then

```
CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=example,DC=com
```

and finally

```
CN=8437C3D8-7689-4200-BF38-79E4AC33DFA0,CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=example,DC=com'
```

So I neded either have feature in unboundId ldap Sdk to be a bit more intelligent or have a feature in apache directory studio to export parents first.

Comment: There is a tool called ldifsort that will fix the LDIF file for you. Google for it you can easily find several references for it. I believe it originally came from SUN Microsystems or Netscape.
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=LDIF%20Sort%20Tools

Comment: Thank you for your comment, But using this link I didn't get the answer how to get anf run this tool locally.

Comment: This seems like a relatively simple problem to address: read in the LDIF objects, sort them based on the path length of their dn (the number of comma-delimited components in the dn), and you're done.

Comment: I tried it but the problem that in a dump I see some several lines like this:
`
dn:: Q049aXZhbiDQl9GD0LXQutGJ0LwsQ049VXNlcnMsREM9aW5ubyxEQz10ZWNo
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: user
`

Althought I exported the ldif using root `DC=hello,DC=world`

Comment: Those items like "dn:: Q049aXZhbiDQl9GD0LXQutGJ0LwsQ049VXNlcnMsREM9aW5ubyxEQz10ZWNo" imply there are "binary" entries present in the DN.
And Google for ldifsort there are a lot of references.

Comment: @ jwilleke There are a lot of information but I can't combine it get the working solution. Will appreciate if you could provide detailed answer

Comment: @jwilleke For me it looks extremely weird that I can't just export dump from ldap server and then use it to import to another server without any weird manipulations